# Convert following curl commands to equivalent java code

Tags: java, curl, cookies, httpclient, centrify

I am trying to use centrify APIs

Following curl commands work properly

```
curl -H "X-CENTRIFY-NATIVE-CLIENT:1" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d     "{User: '*****,Version: '1.0', TenantId: ''  }"     'https://****.cellwe.samsungknox.com/Security/StartAuthentication' --dump-header     headers.txt

curl -H "X-CENTRIFY-NATIVE-CLIENT:1" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{TenantId: '***', SessionId: 'qyrOp_Dvg-btRLQRtjzS2n1AeE2s3tpDh1V68A3TM8Y1', MechanismId: 'tKrhMSCSkUCGzPj2C1aTg1fFrWc75XY-BOhuu63qa9k1',Action: 'Answer', Answer: '****'}"  'https://****.cellwe.samsungknox.com/security/AdvanceAuthentication' --dump-header headers.txt

curl -H "X-CENTRIFY-NATIVE-CLIENT:1" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d "{UUID:'*****'}"  -b headers.txt 'https://****.cellwe.samsungknox.com/UserMgmt/GetUserInfo'
```

I am not able to write the equivalent java code, because, some cookies are not transferred through request.

Please refer the following API guide as well as sample program in .net

API guide
http://developer.centrify.com/site/global/documentation/api_guide/using_the_api/index.gsp

Sample Program
http://community.centrify.com/t5/TechBlog/Customized-Integration-of-Centrify-User-Suite-All-About-REST/ba-p/18769

Comment: You can add cookies using [CookieHandler.getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html#getDefault--), before connecting to the URL.

Comment: What about using `Apache HTTP Client` with same parameters

Comment: note also you do not have to send the auth token you get back as a cookie, you can send it as an oauth bearer token (in a header)